# How to forcefully cascade the font-family to button element inside a <td> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a word press like website where user define configuration for their original web site. Now user has set font for `<td>` as `comic sans ms`. And it works perfectly fine when the web site is rendered. However there is a button also in one of the `<td>` element. That does not respect the `<td>` font. Since its a dynamic (configuration) based web site. I don't have alot of flexibility.

[FIDDLE SAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/unbreakable/mLoqLv0h/)

I found one solution on google where it says I should add `font-family: inherit` to the button element. Is there any way to forcefully cascade the font to all the child element whatever be it so that I do not need to change anything in the `button element` or some minimal change.

```
<table border=1>
<tr><td> test 1 </td></tr>
<tr><td> test 2 </td></tr>
<tr><td> test 3 </td></tr>
<tr><td> test 4 </td></tr>
<tr> <td><input type="button" style="width:130px;" value="Reserve"> </td></tr>
</table>


TD{font-family: Comic Sans MS; font-size: 10pt;}
```

Comment: Anyone using Comic Sans has no right to be changing websites. Please Explain to them that font went out of fashion about 20 years ago (except for pre-schoolers) :)

Comment: I will write a javascript alert.. :D   If I just want to apply the cascading on the font-family and not on any other styles. Is that also possible. Please guide me. I mean the cascading on button should be of just the font-family attribute. In plain english option 1: `td, td * just for font-famiy` option 2: `td, td inputtype[button] but just for font-family`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should get the job done.

```
TD,
TD *
{
  font-family: 'Comic Sans MS'; 
  font-size: 10pt;
}
```

---

Update, per your third question.   I am guessing you are modifying the style to a third-party app that you don't have the ability to change the HTML for?  The following is starting to get a bit hacky, but works.

The first definition applies styles to the table cell and to all child elements of the cell EXCEPT ones that have a type of button.   The second definition applies styles only to child elements of the table cell that have a type of button.

```
TD,
TD *:not([type=button])
{
    color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.9); /* example purposes */
    font-family: 'Comic Sans MS'; 
    font-size: 10pt;
}

TD input[type=button]
{
    font-family: 'Comic Sans MS';
}
```

Comment: Below answer suggest, I just need one TD with *. Is that okey. Or I should follow your approach?

Comment: Also, if I just want to target `<input> button`. Do we have a hack for that?

Comment: `TD` will target that tag. `TD *` will target its children.

Comment: I am sorry for being needy. If I just want to apply the cascading on the font-family and not on any other styles. Is that also possible. Please guide me. I mean the cascading on button should be of just the font-family attribute. In plain english option 1: `td, td * just for font-famiy` option 2: `td, td inputtype[button] but just for font-family`

Comment: Then don't include the font-size in the css definition?

Comment: I might have ten css elements for td. And I want all of them to be there. but for the button out of ten only the font-family attribute of `<td>` should be respected. With current design all the td css elements overwrite the default button styles. As per your question if I remove the css definition from `td` I will lose that style for all `td`..

Answer (score 2):

Would targeting the button specifically be an option for your system? Or just targeting everything inside the td

```
TD * {font-family: Comic Sans MS; font-size: 10pt;}
```

Comment: I wanted to target everything inside `<td>`

Comment: Also, if I just want to target <input> button. Do we have a hack for that?

Comment: Double check, because if you just added the * it most likely lost the styling on your cells.   Because now you are just  targeting the elements inside of the TD, and not TD itself.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you. I did not notice that. :)

Comment: Per your second question... use the selector    TD input[type="button"]

Answer (score 1):

```
input, select, textarea, button {
    font-family: inherit;
}
```

Just to be sure to target all form elements this way :-)

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mLoqLv0h/1

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I was looking for some solution where I do no need to alter button element. :)